# What does the phrase "two-wheeled rubber duckie" mean here"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

What does the phrase "two-wheeled rubber duckie" mean in the following sentence from the description of the game Joe Danger Infinity:

*On a **two-wheeled rubber duckie**, you might be dressed as a crash-test dummy.*

I have never seen any "two-wheeled rubber duckies."

I am wondering if the phrase "rubber duckie" refers to a vehicle here.

Comment: In the world of CB slang, sometimes ["Rubber duck" = ***the first vehicle in a convoy***.](https://www.thesharedweb.com/what-does-rubber-duck-mean-in-cb-talk/) So I'm guessing the two-wheeled version means a ***motorbike*** rider leading a trucking convoy, motorcade, or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Based on some quick googling regarding this game, it appears that the character at some point uses a literal two-wheeled rubber duck as a vehicle.

"Two-wheeled rubber duckie" isn't, to my knowledge, a pre-existing term in the English language. A "rubber duck," which is a children's bath toy, also known to children and their parents and the rest of us as a "rubber duckie" or "rubber ducky," is exactly what it sounds like and can be viewed with a google image search.

From my search results, it seems like in this game, as a gag, two wheels are attached to a rubber duckie, making it into a sort of motorbike for the main character to ride.